# is there a php library to proccess credit card information?

Tags: php, credit-card, bank

First, I've research this topic and many adjacent topics and know the risks with storing and processing credit card information. We have taken all the necessary steps to harden our servers and we're also PCI Compliment. Now, let's try to stay on topic here :)

Our system will allow our customers to add their bank account information so they can accept payments from their customers. What we're trying to do is support the most popular/common banks for our clients to use. We can't force our clients to use authorize.net and all the other payment gateways, most are old-fashioned and just have a business bank account.

I was trying to find an open source php library where most banks are already setup, but couldn't find anything. Have someone written something like this? of course we will carefully analyse the coding and add our own security features.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). It's not exactly what you are looking for but somewhat close.